# what code do I use to view a list of items from the model when used to view on the details.cshtml page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I am trying to view a list of products from a salesorder.  It would look like this:

Name OrderDate OrderTotal  ProductsPurchased <<< trying to get it to list the

products that were brought.  Sales Order is connected to a bridge table of SalesorderProduct.  Any suggestions.  I know its suppose to iterate through the model but can't figure it out.

```
      <th>
          @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Customer.Name)
      </th>

      <th>
          @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OrderDate);
      </th>

      <th>
          @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OrderTotal);
      </th>

      <th>
          @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SalesOrderProducts);
      </th>



      <th></th>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Please show us your action code.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
@model SalesOrder

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View";
}

<h2>View</h2>

<div>
    <h4>SalesOrder</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OrderDate)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OrderDate)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OrderTotal)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.OrderTotal)
        </dd>
    </dl>

        @foreach (Product p in Model.SalesOrderProducts)
        {
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.Name)

            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)
            <br/>
        }


</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.SalesOrderId }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks Peter for your help .  I came up with    <th>

              @foreach (var Product in Model.SalesOrderProducts)
              {

                  @Html.DisplayFor(Products => Product.Product.ProductName)
              }

                           
          </th>
and this works!!